# Chrome App Persistent Filesystem Storage not reliable

Tags: google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I am having issues with my google chrome app and filestorage.

The app is run online and gathers files to store offline so that it should be able to function properly offline later. It does this for the most part but *sometimes* but rarely after a computer restart or restarting the browser it seems to be missing the files in filesystem...

I guess my question is, how do i ensure that Persistent storage remains persistent?

**Edit:**

### Code

**Request filesystem**

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(
window.PERSISTENT, 200*1024*1024,
    function(filesystem) {
        directory.fs = filesystem;
        //Start Application
    },
    filesystemerrorHandler
);
```

**Save a File from remote to local filesystem**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', fileurl, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: blobtype});
        directory.fs.root.getFile(name, {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.onwrite = function(e) {};
                writer.onerror = function(e) { console.log("error"); console.log(e); };
                var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: blobtype});
                writer.write(blob);
                var url = fileEntry.toURL();
                if ( typeof(callback) == 'function' ) {
                    //Save url to indexeddb for recall later
                    //Returns format of: filesystem:chrome-extension://nlipipdnicabdffnohdhhliiajoonmgm/persistent/xxxxxxxxxxxx.png
                    callback(url);    
                }
            }, filewriteerrorHandler2);
        }, filewriteerrorHandler);
    }
    else {
        if ( typeof(callback) == 'function' ) callback(false);
    }
};
```

**Recalling the downloaded file example**

```
<img src="filesystem:chrome-extension://nlipipdnicabdffnohdhhliiajoonmgm/persistent/xxxxxxxxxxxx.png">
```

Now for the most part this will work. However, sometimes, if the computer has been restarted or the browser restarted. If I use the app again the image will not show, this is giving me the impression that the filesystem has been cleared for this app.

What steps, or what area should I be looking at to prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: How about some code so we can try to reproduce the issue? Also OS, Chrome version, etc. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist for more suggestions.

Comment: Question edited for code

Comment: At what point do you save the file to the local file system? As long as you're saving the file, it should be persisted properly. If it isn't please find a way to reproduce the problem and file a bug at http://crbug.com.

Comment: At the line: `writer.write(blob);`
I then use `var url = fileEntry.toURL();` to for the file reference.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to figure out the different code snippets fit together. Could you provide a more complete example showing the problem? It is hard to work out what would be wrong from what you've provided.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I finally found the issue. I was trying to store more than I was allocating: 200*1024*1024

Comment: I increased the number of bytes and now all is good. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the amount of bytes allocated to the app worked.
I was storing more than i was allocating.

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(
    window.PERSISTENT, 200*1024*1024,    <====
    function(filesystem) {
        directory.fs = filesystem;
        //Start Application
    },
    filesystemerrorHandler
);
```

Comment: For anyone if the answer does not work, you could encounter another problem which still cause persistent data lost after restart the Chrome, see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755696/chrome-app-persistent-filesystem-files-lost-after-chrome-restarts/23772536#23772536