# Chrome App, persistent FileSystem, files lost after chrome restarts

Tags: google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I'm developing a Chrome App which uses HTML5 FileSystem with persistent storage, my data was lost after chrome get restarted, I tested several times, 9 times out of 10 data lost after restart, I have fired an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375029&thanks=375029&ts=1400548207) on Chromium site, I want to know if there is workaround or something I did mistake. here is my code:

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 120*1024*1024, function(fs) {
    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            done && done();
        };      
        writer.write(blob);
    }
    fs.root.getFile(path, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}, fail);
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178276/chrome-app-persistent-filesystem-storage-not-reliable) some guy had asked, but I am sure I set quota(120M) big enough. 
This problem is for Chrome App, for Legacy packaged app, no problem.

UPDATE:
Chrome team has confirmed this problem, the patch will land on Chrome 37.

Answer (score 1):

Answer my own question :)
I think I found the problem, it does a chrome bug but just happen when you uninstall your app then **re-install same app without restart chrome**, for somehow reason, chrome remember the uninstalled apps, it will "delay" to clean up filesystem when chrome next time restarts.

This problem may more serious than you think, if you want the re-installed app works correctly, you have to restart ALL of your computers with same Google account after you uninstall old one at same time, you must make sure all copies are uninstalled from all devices before you re-install, Google will snyc new app to you all devices. otherwise you will get problem when you use that app on one of un-restarted computer.

I have added a comment to my [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375029&thanks=375029&ts=1400548207) to Chrome, wish they will fix it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you uninstalling the app?

Comment: @Xan Because I'm developer, I was testing my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Request unlimitedStorage in the manifest:

   "permissions": [
       "unlimitedStorage"
   ]
2. Use a size of zero in the API call:

   webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 0, haveFileSystem, errorHandler);

In theory the user should be asked to approve a request for some size, but after much testing I've determined that Chrome Apps never do this. Instead, a Chrome App just uses what it wants, similar to apps on OS X, Linux, Windows, etc.

Comment: I often (example: today, with mediaGalleries) see anomalies the the Chrome version I normally use, beta. I keep Canary around, which you can have simultaneously with one of the other channels, for checking. So, you might check this with Canary.

Comment: see my answer, this issue still exists on Canary.

Comment: Thanks for posting that and for all the research behind it.